# Conversion Tracking After Specific Time

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api, conversion-tracking

I want to set up a conversion metric to track when a user has been on a page longer than 30 seconds. I'm confused about Google Adwords. It's provided me with a piece of javascript code to inject into my `body` tag. Here's my problem. There is no obvious piece of code that I see that actually initiates the conversion. Look below:

```
<!-- Google Code for 30+ Seconds on site Conversion Page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
  var google_conversion_id = "my id here";
  var google_conversion_language = "en";
  var google_conversion_format = "3";
  var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
  var google_conversion_label = "the label";
  var google_remarketing_only = false;
/* ]]> */
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
```

My plan is to set up a simple timeout delay in javascript and once those 30 seconds have past, then run the code above. But will that work? I don't see any line that shouts "Hey, this line of code communicates to the google server and initiates this conversion". What do I need to do get this to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, this code doesn't really "run" anything, it just tells the browser to load a script.

To add some delay in that, you need to create the JS element and inject it later in your page.

You could try something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var google_conversion_id = "my id here";
  var google_conversion_language = "en";
  var google_conversion_format = "3";
  var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
  var google_conversion_label = "the label";
  var google_remarketing_only = false;

  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  script.setAttribute('src', '//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js');

  setTimeout(function() {
    head.appendChild(script);
  }, 30000);
</script>
```

Or you could just use the [asynchronous version](https://developers.google.com/adwords-remarketing-tag/asynchronous/) of this ;-)

Comment: Yeah I was thinking something like that. Glad to know it's possible. I'm assuming too that I can apply this in different ways such as appending the script when a button is clicked, etc.

Comment: Yes but as you can see in my updated answer it's probably more efficient to use the asynchronous version of this script, which is really intended to be used programmatically.